# How to implement bar chart or bar graph like below in android

Tags: android, highcharts, android-graphview

[image]

I want to implement bar chart like below where the visible range of bar chart is scrollable. Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: @Niceumang Yeah right now i am using MPChart, The question is how to achieve the bottom scrollable view where the selected portion of the bar chart is only displayed.

Comment: you can use recyclerview for that and add views(your vertical blue bar) dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Highstock with column series type:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    data: [...]
  }],

  navigator: {
    series: {
      type: 'column'
    }
  }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4889/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.series.type